# Javascript and Selenium: problem with function calls

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Hi I'm trying to automate going to google images and downloading a file with all the urls of said images,
I have javascript code that I run in chrome console and it works fine, but I wan't to use it from python.

I tried using Selenium and execute_script, which does work in general however I think there is an issue with using the Javascript function Element.GetBoundingClientRect from Selenium.

After I run `driver.execute_script(script)` I observe in the chrome window (the one that Selenium opened) inside the Chrome console, it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null ...
```

The function call fails at several locations but initially at:

```
function simulateRightClick( element ) {
    var event1 = new MouseEvent( 'mousedown', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        view: window,
        button: 2,
        buttons: 2,
        clientX: element.getBoundingClientRect().x,
        clientY: element.getBoundingClientRect().y
    } );
element.dispatchEvent( event1 );
    var event2 = new MouseEvent( 'mouseup', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        view: window,
        button: 2,
        buttons: 0,
        clientX: element.getBoundingClientRect().x,
        clientY: element.getBoundingClientRect().y
    } );
    element.dispatchEvent( event2 );
    var event3 = new MouseEvent( 'contextmenu', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        view: window,
        button: 2,
        buttons: 0,
        clientX: element.getBoundingClientRect().x,
        clientY: element.getBoundingClientRect().y
    } );
    element.dispatchEvent( event3 );
}
```

Is the problem something to do with it not being able to read position from the Selenium chrome window? If so how do I work around this?

Thanks

Update:

The function simulateRightClick is called in:

```
function grabUrls() {
    var urls = [];
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        var count = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.isv-r a:first-of-type' ).length,
            index = 0;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll(
            '.isv-r a:first-of-type' ), function( element ) {
            // using the right click menu Google will generate the
            // full-size URL; won't work in Internet Explorer
            // (http://pyimg.co/byukr)
            simulateRightClick( element.querySelector( ':scope img' ) );
            // Wait for it to appear on the <a> element
            var interval = setInterval( function() {
                if ( element.href.trim() !== '' ) {
                    clearInterval( interval );
                    // extract the full-size version of the image
                    let googleUrl = element.href.replace( /.*(\?)/, '$1' ),
                        fullImageUrl = decodeURIComponent(
                            getURLParam( googleUrl, 'imgurl' ) );
                    if ( fullImageUrl !== 'false' ) {
                        urls.push( fullImageUrl );
                    }
                    // sometimes the URL returns a "false" string and
                    // we still want to count those so our Promise
                    // resolves
                    index++;
                    if ( index == ( count - 1 ) ) {
                        resolve( urls );
                    }
                }
            }, 10 );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking `simulateRightClick`? The error indicates that `element` is null or `None`.

Comment: @PaulM. It is invoked in a grabUrls() function by: simulateRightClick( element.querySelector( ':scope img') );

Comment: It seems that your call to `querySelector` returns `None` sometimes. It's hard to say what's wrong with it without knowing what `element` is, and what its descendant elements look like.

Comment: I have added the function that calls simulateRightClick

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your post. Your queries look fine to me - not sure what's wrong. Have you tried making your queries simpler, like this?:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll(
            ".isv-r img:first-of-type" ), function( img ) {
            simulateRightClick( img );
...
```

I just tried it in Chrome's console and it seems to select all images.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, but the problem is with the code running from within python through Selenium, the code itself when I execute it manually on my browser works fine!
I have found a solution using a completely different method, I got rid of my existing code (https://forums.fast.ai/t/javascript-issue-while-downloading-images/36743/19)